# magento 2 e mails not sending since https

Tags: magento2, email, cron

We have a Magento 2.1.11 website which started with **http**.

The automatic emails worked fine, but as soon as we put a redirect to **https** then they stopped sending.

Please can anyone help?

Comment: Specific Magento version, and how mail sending is configured?

Comment: Magento version 2.1.11 with settings to system value, and enabled to send. the selected e mail addresses are all live and working apart from sending direct from site.